# Recording signature timestamp

Tags: architecture, client-server

This is a design approach question. I'm working on a feature that would record user's e-signature on a document. 
User fills in some form data, and signs the form with his/her name. On the server we would like to record things like `typed name`, and `timestamp` when the user signed the form. 
Does it make sense to ship the timestamp from client (browser) and save it as `signedTimestamp`?

*Note, that db row would also contain fields like `created` and `modified` which will be generated on the server side when the record is saved.*

The client could have a different timezone (so I would need to ensure the timestamp contains timezone info), and server could be processing the signature data at a slightly later time then client clicked `sign` action button.

The reason for shipping timestamp from client is so we have an accurate representation of when user took the action vs when the server processed the data

Answer (score 1):

I would personally avoid it simply because it calls into question the validity of your timestamp.  Do you really want it debated in the court of law whether your timestamp or their timestamp takes priority?  Especially when their timestamp would easily be manipulated by a bit of javascript?